# Android - Horizontal scroll with "Show more"

Tags: android, listview, horizontalscrollview

I have to create a view like this -

[image]

1. There will be three items shown with a show more option
2. On Click of show more the list will grow to 10 items which will be scrollable .

What could be the optimal way to implement this kind of view ?

Comment: `RecyclerView` with `LinearLayoutManager` orientation set to `HORIZONTAL`

Answer (score 0):

Use [HorizontalScrollView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/HorizontalScrollView.html) 
On the first population of the scrollview detect the click on the 4th position and on the 4th item click reload the data and call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()

Answer (score 0):

fro this purpose you can Add 4 element at first time.and detect which Item is clicked by user if this is on 3rd position then you can add more `element` using this code snippets

```
HorizontalScrollView scrollView = (HorizontalScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scrollView1);

    LinearLayout topLinearLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
   // topLinearLayout.setLayoutParams(android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
    topLinearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL); 

    for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++){



        final ImageView imageView = new ImageView (this);

        imageView.setTag(i);

        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

        topLinearLayout.addView(imageView);

        imageView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Log.e("Tag",""+imageView.getTag());
            }
        });


    }

    scrollView.addView(topLinearLayout);
```

hope so it will work for you.
enjoy your coding time:)

Answer (score 0):

Use [`RecyclerView`](https://developer.android.com/intl/zh-cn/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html) instead.

set the [`LinearLayoutManager`](https://developer.android.com/intl/zh-cn/reference/android/support/v7/widget/LinearLayoutManager.html)'s orientation `HORIZONTAL`, like this:

```
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context, HORIZONTAL, false);
```

Good luck.